# Windows store apps - javascript - element variable

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I was reading the "HTML animation library sample" http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-the-Animation-787f3720  and notice that none of the element variable in the javascript are declared.

Where is the variable declaration or getelement for target1, target2, etc? Note the strict declaration of the top. This is the sample code from Microsoft.

From pointerFeedback.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/pointerFeedback.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            target1.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onPointerDown, false);
            target1.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", onPointerUp, false);
            target2.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onPointerDown, false);
            target2.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", onPointerUp, false);
            target3.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onPointerDown, false);
            target3.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", onPointerUp, false);
        }
    });

    function onPointerDown(evt) {
        WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerDown(evt.srcElement);
    }

    function onPointerUp(evt) {
        WinJS.UI.Animation.pointerUp(evt.srcElement);
    }
})();
```

From pointerFeedback.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pointerFeedback.css" />
    <script src="/js/pointerFeedback.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input" data-win-control="SdkSample.ScenarioInput">
        <p>Use the Pointer Up and Pointer Down animations to
        show tap and click feedback on elements. These animations should be used on elements
        that can be interacted with and can trigger actions. They should not be used on
        elements that are disabled or on standard web controls that already have other feedback, such as buttons.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="output" data-win-control="SdkSample.ScenarioOutput">
        <div class="example">
            <h3>Applied to different sized elements:</h3>
            <p>Click or tap on the boxes below to see the animation.</p>
            <div id="target1" class="large">
                200 pixels
            </div>
            <div id="target2" class="medium">
                100 pixels
            </div>
            <div id="target3" class="small">
                50 pixels
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question! I suspect that every element with a specified 'id' will be automatically made available to JavaScript.

I could confirm this by creating a new project based on the "Blank App" template and adding a new div with id="foobar". Then I started the app and switched to the JavaScript console and voila: a 'foobar' variable was available!

After doing Win8 app development for some months, I never stumbled over this, well done!

Comment: This is true in every browser except Firefox, IIRC.